# Why does Linux use an Initial Ram Disk at boot?

Tags: linux, boot

I was wondering :

What's the goal of using an `initrd` in the first part of the boot process and then use `pivot_root` to put the root on the real disk ? Why not only use what's on the disk ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why not only use what's on the disk ?

You can.  You do not have to use an initrd (or an initramfs, the newer and more widespread version since kernel 2.6.13).

The reason that they are used is that distro kernels are generic and must support a wide range of hardware out of the box.  Some of the drivers for different hardware, crucial to mounting a root filesystem, are possibly mutual exclusive (I'm not sure) but in any case, building all the possibilities in -- which is what you would have to do -- would make for a very massive kernel.

Thus, rather than being built into the kernel, the drivers are in separate binary modules.  This is the primary payload of the initramdfs/initrd; it allows the kernel to load the appropriate drivers for the hardware so that the root filesystem can then be properly mounted.

Answer (score 4):

Before there was such a thing as an initrd, you had to pass the device name of the partition you wanted to use as your root fs on the kernel command line.  The kernel had special one off code to parse this name and recognize a handful of common strings, and translate them to their well known `dev_t` number.  That is to say, that internally the kernel knows about devices simply as a numeric index into an array, and to mount one you have to know its number.

In the days before plug and play and hot plug, when systems had only one or two disks that were always present, this worked OK.  If your root filesystem was `/dev/hda1` then it was always so.  The advent of plug and play blew this out of the water though.  These days you may have a dozen internal disk drives, or usb, iscsi, or what have you, and in the interest of lowering boot times, they are probed in parallel, so their device name can change depending on which one happens to respond first on any given boot, or the order you hot plug them in.  That means your kernel command line specified device name could easily become incorrect and you fail to boot.

To work around that, the UUID was introduced.  By specifying devices by UUID, it doesn't matter whether it is sda or sde, the right drive can always be found.  This does however, require actually looking at the drives and is quite a bit more complex that the simple, static name -> `dev_t` mapping the kernel boot code can do.  It was decided that the kernel is no place for such complexity and so the initrd was born.  It can have whatever utilities it needs to identify what right root device and mount it.  It can also do arbitrarily complex things such as bring up the network and obtain a DHCP lease in order to access an nfs or iscsi root.  Other things you need an initrd for include setting up raid and lvm or crypto for disk access.

Comment: This is a much better and thorough answer than the accepted one.

Answer (score 2):

[chaos](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/52727/chaos) perfectly summarized it. I'd just add that an initial ramdisk (or *initrd*) is **optional**. There are certain circumstances it is required, for instance when `/usr` lies on a separate filesystem, which used to be advertised as a good practice.

Also, *systemd*, which is found on many Linux distributions, [requires `/usr` to be available at boot](http://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/separate-usr-is-broken/). Otherwise you have to provide an *initrd* that prepares the root filesystem with `/usr` properly mounted prior to switching to the real root.

Having a nice bootsplash screen also requires an *initrd*. All modern, major distributions provide a bootsplash screen instead of the infamous flow of log messages at boot.

Answer (score 1):

The task of the initrd is to make the real root device available and switch into it. The real root device can be (for example) a partition on a hard drive, a nfs share in the network, a filesystem at an USB-stick, a pseudo-filesystem or something else.

Nearly every initrd has a routine called `mountroot`. That's the function that searches for the correct root filesystem and mounts it (normally to `/root` in the initrd itself (don't confuse it with root's home directory)).

The boot manager has to point to the correct location on the disk (or whereever) where the kernel and the initrd is. The kernel is executed and the initrd is unpacked directly into systems RAM. There is normally a script in `/` of the initrd called `init`. Thats the part that mounts the pseudo filesystems (sysfs, procfs, dev, ...). Also there are environment variables that are accessible (over `/proc/cmdline`) such as `debug`, `break`, ...

After the root filesystem has been mounted, the script cleans up and switches to the new root. Then the process in `/sbin/init` overtakes the pid number 1, that was previously the init-scripts pid. From then on there are different mechanisms that make the rest of the boot process (upstart, SysVinit, systemd).